# How do I stop a beakR server instance in a supervisord service

Tags: r, supervisord

I have a short R script which creates with the `beakr`-Package (but it could be Shiny as well) a server instance listening on port `4000`.

```r
library(beakr)

newBeakr() %>% 
  httpGET(path = "/hello", function(req, res, err) {
    print("Hello, World!")
  }) %>% 
  listen(host = "0.0.0.0", port = 4000)
```

I run this script on Linux as a services in `~/etc/services.d/rstats.ini` which I start with `supervisorctl start rstats` and it does its job.

```
[supervisord]
loglevel=warn

[program:rstats]
command=%(ENV_HOME)s/R
directory=%(ENV_HOME)s
autostart=yes
autorestart=yes
```

But how do I probably stop the server? `beakr` has a `beakr::stopServer()` function, but how can I call it, when I use e.g. `supervisorctl stop rstats`. Why do I need that: Sometimes the port is not freed, when I just stop the service. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Seems that you should test for a condition of you choosing. Perhaps inactivity for a specific time or have an input dialog that lets you say "stop".

Comment: Ah, you are saying I should call `beakr::stopServer()` through the server instance. Sounds good, I am going to try that.